# how to write controller test in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm really not sure how to write a controller test.

Given is one of the controller action.

```
  class AccountsController < ApplicationController
    def pstn_rate_imports
        page = params[:page] || 1
        @pstn_rate_imports = @resporg_account_id.pstn_rate_imports.order('created_at desc').page(page).per(10)
        @pstn_rate_import = PstnRateImport.new
      end
   end
```

Now I approach this in 2 way..

1. I can insert data on PSTN Rate import table and then test that.
   and then write a test which probably will verify whether the returned object exactly matches to test result expectation.

Like,

```
get :pstn_rate_imports, id: 1, page: 1
expect(assigns(:pstn_rates_imports)).to eq(expected_result)
```

but here a problem, I would now need to sure of that I insert a correct data on DB (worry about validation etc, etc when creating records)
Also, this does not adhere to the principle that any new chance you introduce should break your test.

2. OR I can mock the ActiveRecord call.

> expect_any_instance_of(ResporgAccountId).to
>   receive(:pstn_rate_imports) { some_arel }
>
> expect(some_arel).to receive(:order).with('created_at desc') { some_arel }
>
> expect(some_arel).to receive(:page).with('1') { some_arel }
>
> expect(some_arel).to receive(:per).with(10) { some_arel }
>
> get :pstn_rate_imports, id: 1, page: 1

This ensures that if I change anything the test would fail. But the problem is that I'm not sure how to `mock the arel object or ActiveRecord method that returns an arel object`.

So what is the correct way to write controller test in Rails.

Answer (score 0):

The main principle is writing a test that covers the tested object functionality only.

So you need to:

- test the logic (`pstn_rate_imports` method) creating a relative test for the model method
- test variables assigning and controller's specific logic (like `.order`) in the controller. 
  Model's methods (like `pstn_rate_imports`) should be stubbed for sure. You can read more about the stubbing [here](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-99/docs/method-stubs/allow-with-a-simple-return-value).

Comment: that make sense but stubbing a Model method like `where` return a relational. who to do that.? and when the method has lot of ar chaining it become increasingly difficult example `.where().order().page().per()` increasingly difficult to mock each method with the proper arguments

Comment: >> Model method like where return a relational
you can stub it and return the desired relational (just define it in `let`)
>> increasingly difficult to mock each method
not so difficult, it's ok to check that methods are called with appropriate args, that's it, you can skip the logic checking for the standard methods like the pagination ones.

Comment: can you give an example.

Comment: That's taking too much time, sorry. What I can is to recommend a great RSpec book - https://leanpub.com/everydayrailsrspec